# magento can't upload large csv file

Tags: magento, csv, file-upload

this is my file upload code when i try to upload file which has size more than 75mb i can't upload file i did't get any error i also change php.ini file still its not working

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('csvupload');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('csv'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'uploads';
                    $fname="customer.csv";
                    $uploader->save($path, $fname );
                    $filename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
```

can anybody give solution?

Comment: Why cant u try magmi?

Answer (score 1):

It's not Magento but PHP/server settings that are the issue. By default PHP has a much smaller max file and post size.

Check out this article on uploading large files. Via your htaccess you can change these values. Also make sure the execution_time is high enough to process the file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 80M
php_value post_max_size 80M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file name should be accurate. I guess some problem in your filename.

Replace

```
$fname="customer.csv";
```

with

```
$fname="/your/file/path/customer.csv";
```

Hope this works.

Comment: but i also try for small file so i can upload that file i can't upload only large file